# java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main] on Unity

Tags: java, android, unity3d, исключения

Приложение на Unity. Очень часто стала появляться данная ошибка (примерно у 10% пользователей)
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 5.6.2p4
Device model      : samsung SM-G570F
Caused by
  at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw (Canvas.java:1311)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1398)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:897)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap.java:753)
  at com.unity3d.player.i.onLayout (Unknown Source)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18010)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18010)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18010)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1742)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18010)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:344)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:281)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout (PhoneWindow.java:3175)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18010)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5911)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2784)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2477)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7621)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:911)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:686)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:622)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:897)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7409)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Краши происходят на самых разнообразных устройствах

Comment: Мне кажется стоит как минимум собрать статистику  с каких моделей и при каких условиях крэшется, а потом запастись подобными моделями, открыть свое приложение, подключить и отдебажить

Comment: Unitу платная версия? Splash-Screen используете?